# Programming the start time of the execution of the method - the method to start executing at that time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in my program which executes for a long time. So, I want it to be executed at night, or sometime when the users aren't doing with the app.

The user will enter time and date in a textbox and I will save that value in the db.

Let's say the user enters `27th December 2012, midnight.`

I want the `Example()` method to start executing at that exact time.

Is there a way to program this?

Comment: What is `executes long time`?

Comment: Is this running as a Windows service already?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Hmm no. Why?

Comment: @Srcee, the primary reason for asking is because scheduled jobs generally need to be in a state where they can read the database regularly to determine when they are supposed to wake up and run. Another option is to implement a Windows Workflow service. I think my *general assumption* was that the application scheduling the service isn't necessarily going to be **running** when it's scheduled to execute, therefore the service needs to be decoupled.

Comment: @Srcee It looks odd, that's all.

Comment: What type of database are you running? Can you pull your method out into a console app and schedule a job with `SQL Server Agent`?

Answer (score 2):

There are various options, what have you found?

You can for example run a task through Windows task scheduler, or have a service running that regularly checks whether the time to start a specific task has approached, and if so, does so.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably look into an existing library for **job scheduling** such as [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/). Especially if you are planning on having recursive jobs.

Quartz may be embedded into an existing application or run separately as a stand-alone app.

Answer (score 0):

Create a System.Timers.Timer object. Calculate the time the user has entered minus the current time in milliseconds. Pass that time to the constructor of the timer with your method as its Elapsed event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (DateTime.Now == your time)
{
    // do your process
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here - you can either have a service that polls the database for work to execute, and when it's time it executes the Example method.
You could programatically place create a windows schedule task and that way you don't need to poll.

There is no method in MVC however to get a timed call back that far in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah1h85ch.aspx) to start your method after some delay:

```
DateTime date = // when you need method to run
TimeSpan dueTime = date - DateTime.Now;
Timer timer = new Timer(_ => Example(), null, dueTime, new TimeSpan(0));
```

You can specify period `TimeSpan(24, 0, 0)` to execute method daily.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ulises mentioned you could use a job scheduler or if it is possible to separate the logic of that task, you can use windows scheduler. But if you need to do it inside your program it's just a matter of coding; first the supervisor method:

```
static void Supervisor()
{
    while (true)
    {
        DateTime time = ReadTimeFromFile();

        if (Math.Abs((DateTime.Now - time).TotalMinutes) <= 1)
        {
            DeleteTimeFile(); // to indicate task is done

            RunTask();

            break;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Then write the target time in a file.
And at start of your program (or other proper place):

```
new Task(Supervisor, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```

It is very important to use TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning option to initialize a separate thread for this outside of you ThreadPool.